# Only load visible images in Ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The frontend of my blog uses Ember.js -> **http://ali.dj**

On the frontpage I only show excerpts of the five latest posts which contain max. 1 image. Yet, all images are loaded for these five posts in the background.

I would like the additional images to be loaded only after showing the full post. How can I achieve this?

[image]

*Lazy load plugins can't be used as I get the raw HTML of each post from the database. I decided to move the markdown parser to the server-side to reduce the complexity to O(1) and not to send a markdown-parser to the client.*

Comment: Could you provide any code ? It's pretty hard to tell without any additional code how your application is built. But naturally you would have route view/post/1 In this route.js file you could query for the post's image in the model hook.e.g> store.query('dir/filerepository', {post : 1} ) <== resolves to given image.

Comment: If you ping me on the ember-community slack I have solutions I can walk you through where I have done this using a combination of an async-image component and an in-viewport service.  A standardized solution to this will be landing in smoke-and-mirrors today.

Comment: Actually I missed the part where you pre-did the html server side, can you wrap the non-visible part of the post in an if block to prevent render until ready?